# Fix blogger black images

Tags: html, blogger

On my website (howtoplaystation.com), the images of the popular posts on the right side are surrounded by a black color. Can someone help me fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/041ZA.png)

I tried some CSS codes, but didn't help.

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail {
    width: initial;
    height: 70px;
}

.PopularPosts ul li img {
    object-fit: fill !important;
}
```

I expect that the complete images will be in the circles, and not surrounded by black colors.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I would solve this would be:

Change this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

to this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

And this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

to this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 3px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: scale(1.65);
}
```

Basically, change the border, radius and size to the parent element, and add an object-fit and scale the image a bit to hide out those black stripes that are part of the image itself.

Personally, I would also change the border color to any other than white since the background of the main element is also a light color, so maybe use a skyblue for this border instead but that's a personal taste.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Now it looks OK, but I would like to change the position of the image that's in the circle, because as you can see it is a little bit weird now. Can you maybe tell me how I can zoom the picture a little bit out? Thank you again!

Comment: To zoom in or out, change the value in transform: scale(1.65); Just play with it these numbers until it's the way you like.

Comment: Also I would sugest you change the padding to 0.

Comment: It is OK now, not?

Comment: Looks good enough. I would add the box-shadow that you removed from the image before to the parent element too... and maybe change it to box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

Comment: I added it back but nothing changed now? I added: webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

Comment: No need to add any of the border-radius as it is already there in the PARENT element: the .PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a,  not the .PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img where you added them back. That is the image element and in there those styles do nothing as you have a overflow:hidden in the parent element that will hide them. If you want to see the shadow around the image, in this case you must add the box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); to the PARENT element: the .PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a.

Comment: Oh, And since most browser this days don't require the prefix, you can skip the webkit and moz ones. For further info about CSS prefix: http://shouldiprefix.com/ I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove box-shadow by changing this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

to this:

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did what you said, but nothing actually changed.

Comment: @JongeRoge I just went to https://www.howtoplaystation.com/ and the shadow is gone.

Comment: I don’t know what you thought I meant to fix, but I’m talking about the black color in the circles. In the circles there are the thumbnails of my videos, surrounded by a black color. I want the black color to be gone. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/041ZA.png thank you

Comment: @JongeRoge here what I see right now: https://imgur.com/eomnROJ Is your cache cleared?

Comment: But I want to remove this: https://snipboard.io/bEYzgV.jpg and make the whole picture be in the circle without the black colors. Thank you.

Comment: @JongeRoge Those black bars are literally part of the image.  If you edit the image, you'd be good.

Comment: But how can I change the images? I'm using Blogger.